# What is an example of a uni-modal symmetric non-Gaussian probability density function ?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What are examples of Unimodal Symmetric probability density functions that are not Gaussian ?

I searched online and found this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality

This article gives 4 examples:

1. Cauchy distribution
2. Student's t-distribution
3. chi-squared distribution
4. exponential distribution

But chi-squared and exponential are not symmetric.  The student-t distribution looks exactly like a Gaussian.

The only one that seems to be non Gaussian and symmetric is Cauchy. But the [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) says it is a ratio of two normal random variables.

So I'm wondering if there are any unimodal symmetric distributions that have nothing to do with Gaussian (or normal) distributions?

Comment: How do you define "have nothing to do with"?

Comment: Gotta correct you on the comment on Student-$t$ "looking exactly" as a Gaussian. It is a generalization that allows for "heavier tails", controlled by parameter $\nu$. When $\nu\to\infty$ the distribution is Gaussian, but in other cases it is not. It might look like one, but that does not mean it is Gaussian by any measureable metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a symmetric version of the exponential distribution called the Laplace distribution, with pdf:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2a} e^{-| x | /a}, -\infty < x < \infty$

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of the difference of two uniform distributions is an example. The *double exponential* distribution, with density $\exp(-|x|)/2$. The convolution of the above two.